# I need to set up two independent variables in applescript and check to see if they both occur

Tags: triggers, controller, applescript

I am using a program called "MidiPipe" to use a midi controller to trigger actions on my mac.

Basically what I need to happen is when I press two keys on my midi controller simultaneously, I need an action to happen, but the messages come in separately. I need set one message as a variable, then set it to the side check if the other message comes in, and then check if they are the correct combination of messages. If it is, I need an action to occur. Here is an image of my Alist which is basically the input of of my midi controller when I press down the key 21 and 24. In addition here is the code I currently have which is not working.

http://pastebin.com/sD7vxVpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcdxL.png

Thanks for reading

~Frank

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this :

```
property lastSecondItemis21 : false --item 2 of last message 

on runme(message)
    if (item 1 of message = 144) and (item 2 of message = 21) and (item 3 of message > 0) then
        set lastSecondItemis21 to true
    else if lastSecondItemis21 then
        set lastSecondItemis21 to false
        if (item 1 of message = 144) and (item 2 of message = 24) and (item 3 of message > 0) then
            --<do action>
        end if
    end if
end runme
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for you. We are going to create a stay-open applescript application. This application will run all the time. This example has 2 variables you can use, key1 and key2. Whenever I ask the application to "run" it will tell me the state of the two variables... in this case whether they have a value.

So to try this example, the first thing you need to do is save this code as a stay-open application. I called my application "stayOpenApp".

```
property key1 : missing value
property key2 : missing value

on run
    if key1 is not missing value and key2 is not missing value then
        set theMessage to "Both keys have values."
    else if key1 is not missing value then
        set theMessage to "Only key 1 has a value."
    else if key2 is not missing value then
        set theMessage to "Only key 2 has a value."
    else
        set theMessage to "Neither key has a value."
    end if

    tell me to activate
    display dialog theMessage
end run

on quit
    -- reset the variables before quitting
    set key1 to missing value
    set key2 to missing value
    continue quit
end quit

on runMe()
    tell me to run
end runMe

on setKey1(theValue)
    set key1 to theValue
end setKey1

on getKey1()
    return key1
end getKey1

on setKey2(theValue)
    set key2 to theValue
end setKey2

on getKey2()
    return key2
end getKey2
```

You will notice it has the 2 variables as properties. At the bottom of the script are getters and setters for each variable. This allows an external applescript to either get the value of the variable or set the value of a variable. To follow this example create the following separate applescript and run it...

```
tell application "stayOpenApp" to launch
```

That code will get stayOpenApp to start. Now at any time we can run this code to get stayOpenApp to tell us the status of the variables...

```
tell application "stayOpenApp" to runMe()
```

If at some point we want to change the status of a variable we can use this...

```
tell application "stayOpenApp" to setKey1(1)
```

Now if you again check the status of the variables using runMe() you will notice the change.

So using these techniques you have a method to pass information to variables of a running applescript and also check the status of the variables. I hope this gives you some ideas of how to solve your problem. Good luck.